# Suggestion needed for Apache Spark Problem set For Practicing

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am planning to improve my Apache Spark skill. I wanted to know if there are any websites that offers coding problems and platform to solve for those using Apache Spark and Scala. I tried looking up on the websites like HackerRank, LeetCode, TopCoder but I couldn't see any problems for Spark. I know Databricks and Cloudera has Free Notebooks and Virtual machines respectively for practice. I feel comfortable if I have set of problems to solve and I will be more productive with that.

If no websites that provides this facility yet, can someone give me a better way I can practice and improve my skill?.

Comment: Coursera has a Spark course that probably comes with some homework problems that you can solve

Comment: Thank you @sinanspd. Can you please give me the course title or the link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try free notebooks: https://databricks.com
A good site to get free datasources: https://www.kaggle.com where you can also find competitions (https://www.kaggle.com/competitions)

For Spark, I've not found a site similar like HackerRank where you have a set of problems to solve and get results from these online judges. But you can try courses such as Udemy, coursera, etc, they usually provide examples and support for questions with the instructor.

Comment: Thank you @Cesar A. Mostacero for the response. This is what I thought but wanted to confirm my understanding with others, that is the reason for the question. I would have upvoted your answer but I do not have enough reputation to do that yet.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting Udemy and Coursera. let me see if they have any problem set and support for discussions. This is a good alternative until mainstream platforms like HackerRank and others pick up Spark and add problem sets.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a Linux machine so that you could setup the Spark environment. I recommend to register for a **Google Cloud Pltform (GCP)**. You can create a free account using your Google account, and they offer **USD $300 for 12 months** (whichever exhausts first). Once you create an account, with just a few clicks and basic settings (like number of cores, RAM, HDD, OS, etc.), you can create a **Google Compute Engine (GCE)**, which is basically a virtual machine.

You can then install Spark by following these tutorial links:

[DEZYRE](https://www.dezyre.com/apache-spark-tutorial/apache-spark-installation-tutorial)

[DATAFLAIR](https://data-flair.training/blogs/spark-installation-standalone-mode/)

Happy learning! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Problem with using a public cloud like Google, AWS etc. is that you will spend a lot of time installing and configuring your hadoop cluster, scala, spark, notebooks. If you are interested in admin level tasks, go for public cloud. Otherwise, use a pre-configured server and start learning coding right away. I would strongly recommend getting access to an already established service provider like https://cloudxlab.com . I use it to do my research and learning. They provide a complete suite of tools like Hadoop cluster, Spark, Kafka, Pig, Hive, Storm, Jupyter notebooks etc.